# Problem using italics in fonts with optical size feature

Tags: fonts, italic

I come across a strange problem when using fonts with different optical sizes. When compiling the following example (using either lualatex or xetex)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
01. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

02. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

03. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

04. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

05. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

06. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

07. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

08. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

09. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

10. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

11. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

12. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

13. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

14. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

15. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

16. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

17. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

18. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

19. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

20. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

21. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

22. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

23. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

24. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

25. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

26. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

27. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

28. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

29. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

30. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

31. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

32. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

33. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

34. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

35. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

36. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

37. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

38. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

39. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

40. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

41. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

42. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

43. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

44. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

45. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

46. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

47. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

48. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

49. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

50. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

51. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

52. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

53. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

54. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

55. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

56. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

57. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

58. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

59. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

60. Everything is fine \emph{Everything is fine}

\end{document}
```

I get the following message in the log file

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `EU2/EBGaramond(0)/m/sl' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `EU2/EBGaramond(0)/m/it' tried instead on input line 100.
```

This error always shows up in the second line of the second page (to check this i've inserted vertical spaces to change the place where the new page starts), and when using fonts with different optical sizes available.

In the case of EB Garamond, this is not very problematic, since the output looks as it should. But, when using Arno Pro (at 10pt), the italics from the second line of the second page on are larger than they should be (because the wrong size is being used). Here is what the start of the second page looks like (using Arno Pro, 10pt)

[image]

The pdf reader i'm using (evince) tells me that the fonts used are ArnoPro-SmTex, ArnoPro-ItalicSmTex (as expected) and ArnoPro-Italic (that should not be used).

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

I'm using texlive.

`This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013070107 (rev 4627)  (format=lualatex 2014.5.3)
Package: fontspec 2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX`

Comment: It might be helpful to also add a screen shot that depicts the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @egreg: what versions of LuaTex and fontspec are you using?

Comment: I can't test this (don't have the font), but just out of curiosity, what happens if you replace `\emph{}` with `\textit{}` and\or `\textsl{}`. Note that the latter is not italic but slanted.

Comment: @Pouya: Using `\textit{}` results in exactly the same output. Using `\textsl{}` the output looks as it should, the correct fonts are used, but i still get the same messages about font shape m/sl not being available, only now at line 5 (the first line of the document).

Comment: I can reproduce the OP's log messages when compiling with ``EB Garamond`` under ``LuaLaTeX``.